# Unable to correctly import framework into xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode4, import, workspace

I'm trying to add KKGridView to my project. I've followed thier description from github as best I can:

- Create a new workspace in Xcode in the same directory as your existing *.xcodeproj.
- Drag in your existing Xcode project
- Locate your copy of KKGridView, drag KKGridView.xcodeproj into the
  workspace so that it stays at the top of the hierarchy, just like
  your original project.
- In the Build Phases section of your original project, link your
  project with libKKGridView.a.
- Now, simply import KKGridView just like an Apple framework:

But libKKGridView appears in red in my project, and I am unable to import any of the code with

```
#import <KKGridView/KKGridView.h>
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this file physically to your folder,and then add file to xcode from there.Drag and drop create this problem sometimes.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: which file? The libKKGridView.a file?

Comment: @Kwame : Copy libKKGridView.a physically to your folder,and then add file to xcode from there.Is it okay for you now to understand?

Comment: Thanks iApple. That seems to work. I was hoping to do it the way it says in KKGridView's documentation ie with workspaces, but that seems to not be a straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the .h files as well

Comment: do you mean copy all the .h files? I was thinking of doing that, but that seems to go against the idea of importing frameworks. I guess that would be a last resort.